# Read a section/part of a long .txt asset file in dart - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a .txt file in assets folder that I can read, but now I want to read a section of the file maybe from point A to point B. My current code to read the whole file's contents is shown below

```
  Future<void> readText() async {
    final String response =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/longtextfile.txt');
    setState(() {
      dataFromFile = response;
    });
  }
```

then I display like this...

```
             child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  dataFromFile,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
              ),
```

how do I read the files contents line by line from point A to point B of the long txt file?

longtextfile.txt looks like

```
1. song 1
 some text
 some text
 some text

2. song 2
 some text
 some text
 some text

3. song 3
 some text 
 some text 
 some text
```

so I want to read for example song 2 only, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string into lines by using [split](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/LineSplitter/split.html) from the LineSplitter class:

```
final lines = LineSplitter.split(dataFromFile);
```

Then you can do anything you like with the lines. You can take only a few of them, have seperate widgets for them that have seperate style, whatever you want.

---

Since you posted your data now. You can for example get the song that is number 2 by looking at the lines using the [skipWhile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/skipWhile.html) and [takeWhile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/takeWhile.html) methods:

```
final song2 = lines.skipWhile(line => !line.startWith('2'))
                   .takeWhile(line => !line.startWith('3'));

for(final line in song2) {
    print(line);
}
```

Comment: I'm a newbie, please give an example of looping from point a to point b of the 'lines' within a widget

Comment: @user9784676 I edited the answer based on your data.